# Some questions on Alien Dalvik

Tags: android, mobile, jvm, google-play, dalvik

Fellow developers,

as you see it at Engadget, a company developed 'Alien Dalvik', a middleware enabling Dalvik runs on any other platform like Meego. 
 http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/08/myriad-alien-dalvik-runs-android-apps-on-any-phone-starting/

If the middleware got ported to other platform, let's say MeeGo, then what channel do users get application downloaded at? Android market?

Answer (score 1):

the original apk can't be supported on the alien dalvik. the apk must be repackaged. http://www.myriadgroup.com/software/android/myriad%20alien%20dalvik.aspx?sc_lang=en

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be enough publicly available information to make a solid determination yet, but I would say: not Android Market, because that's only (legally) available to Android partners on Google branded devices.

There are other Android app marketplaces with different policies.  Wait and see.